# Remove submenu for 'Add Order' in WooCommerce on WordPress admin dashboard

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, backend, dashboard

My WooCommerce version is 4.5.2.

I will like to remove the '**Add order**' for a custom user so that it cannot access `wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=shop_order`.

[image]

I have created a custom user using *User Role Editor* with the following permissions:

[image]

With this, the user can only view existing orders, and click the order preview to update to 'Completed'.

I tried using this:

```php
remove_submenu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=shop_order', 'post-new.php?post_type=shop_order');
```

...but the Order main menu becomes not accessible.

I came across this post [Remove or hide "add new" button on woocommerce on bulk order panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46432147/remove-or-hide-add-new-button-on-woocommerce-on-bulk-order-panel), which hides the 'Add order' from the page using CSS.

I wish someone can point me to a direction on how to achieve what I am looking for.

---

**UPDATE:**

Based on 7uc1f3r's answer, this is my output

```
[edit.php?post_type=shop_order] => Array
    (
        [5] => Array
            (
                [0] => Orders 
                [1] => edit_shop_orders 
                [2] => edit.php?post_type=shop_order
            )
            
        [10] => Array
            ( 
                [0] => Add order 
                [1] => edit_shop_orders 
                [2] => post-new.php?post_type=shop_order 
            )
    )
```

Using the provided solution, I use this so that the custom user cannot Add order and access wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=shop_order:

```
    unset( $submenu['edit.php?post_type=shop_order'][10][0] );
    unset( $submenu['edit.php?post_type=shop_order'][10][1] );
    unset( $submenu['edit.php?post_type=shop_order'][10][2] );
```

In addition, I apply CSS to hide the 'Add order' at the admin panel:

```
    ul.wp-submenu.wp-submenu-wrap {
        display: none !important;
    }
```

It now looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using `WC 4.4.1` & `WC 4.6.0` and in both versions there is no possibility to create a new order from the menu.

**UPDATE:** Due to the output you posted, this should suffice to remove "Order: add new"

```php
function action_admin_menu() {
    global $menu, $submenu;

    // Unset 'Order: add new'
    unset( $submenu['edit.php?post_type=shop_order'][10] );
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'action_admin_menu' );
```

---

Optional: For "Products: add new" and DEBUGGING you could use

```php
// DEBUG: This displays the complete wordpress admin menu on your dashboard for admin only. (Remove afterwards)
function debug_admin_menus() {
    global $menu, $submenu, $pagenow;
    if ( current_user_can('manage_options') ) {
        if( $pagenow == 'index.php' ) {  // print on dashboard
            echo '<pre>', print_r( $menu, 1 ), '</pre>'; // top level menus
            echo '<pre>', print_r( $submenu, 1 ), '</pre>'; // submenus
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_notices', 'debug_admin_menus' );

function action_admin_menu() {
    global $menu, $submenu;

    // Unset 'Products: add new'
    unset( $submenu['edit.php?post_type=product'][10] );
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'action_admin_menu' );
```

---

Related:

- [Change WooCommerce products menu title in WordPress admin dashboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61106895/change-woocommerce-products-menu-title-in-dashboard/)
- [How to rename a menu tab under WooCommerce tab on WordPress admin dashboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60445980/how-to-rename-a-menu-tab-under-woocommerce-tab-on-wordpress-admin/)